# pasar datos de un json a una variable Angular

Tags: angular, angular7, jsonarray

Estoy tratando de pasar los datos que recojo de un json a una variable, trate de hacerlo con un for pero angular no entra en dicho for 
aqui tengo un  mat-autocomplete que me selecciona el dato del array que quiero pasar a variable

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-label>MEDICO</mat-label>
   <input type="tex" matInput [matAutocomplete]="autoneduci"
   [(ngModel)]="identificacion" name =  "cod_medico"  />
   <mat-autocomplete #autoneduci="matAutocomplete"
   [displayWith]="displaymedi">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let lismedi of medico"  [value]="lismedi"    >
         {{lismedi.identificacion_med}}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

aqui tengo la el componente con la función del  for que me recorrería dicho json

```
 export class CitaPacienteComponent implements OnInit {
  newPacienteCita: cita_pacientes = {
    ingreso: 0,
    cod_paciente: 0,
    cod_cita:   this.idcita
      };
      newMedicoCita: cita_medico = {
        cod_medico: null,
        cod_cita: this.idcita
      };
lado = 0;
  myControl = new FormControl();
   paciente: any = [];
  medico: any = [];
  identificacion: any [];
  constructor(

    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CitaPacienteComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public idcita: any,
    private mySql: mySql,

     ) { }
 ngOnInit() {
  this.paciente
  this.medico
  this.pacientes();
  this.medicos();    
} 
onclicno() {
  this.dialogRef.close();
} 
displayFn(subject){
  return subject ? subject.identificacion_pac : undefined;
}

displaymedi(subject){
  return subject ? subject.identificacion_med : undefined;
}
pacientes() {
  this.mySql.getpacientes().subscribe(
    res => {
      this.paciente = res
      },
    err => console.error('error visor', err)
  );

}

medicos() {
  this.mySql.getmedico().subscribe(
    res => {
      this.medico = res  
        console.log("LA LISTA ES  son:", this.medico);
    },
    err => console.error('error visor', err)
  );
}

agendarCita(){
  console.log('el data ',this.identificacion);

  for (let a = 0; a > this.identificacion.length; a++) {
    this.i = this.identificacion.identificacion_med
    console.log ("Block statement execution no." + a);
  }}
```

lo que quiero realizar con este código es que me traiga desde la base de datos una lista desplegable donde se seleccione la cédula de un usuario y después se envié a un formulario para insertar en otras tablas de la base de datos

Comment: puedes añadir el código de tu componente para ver realmente lo que estás haciendo?

Comment: @SergioRubio, Gracias por el consejo, acabo de subir el componente para que sea mas claro lo que trato de  hacer, agradecería si alguno de los compañeros sabe o me da algún consejo de como resolver mi  inconveniente